# Cannot load a php page with nginx - 502 Bad gateway

Tags: php, nginx

I have PHP 7.2.17 and Nginx 1.15.9 on Ubuntu 19.04.
I have this nginx configuration :

```
server {  
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name dev.frameworkcms.com;

  set $rootpath "/var/www/html/perso/framework-cms test";  

  error_log "/var/www/html/perso/framework-cms test/logs/error.log" error;
  # combined by default
  access_log "/var/www/html/perso/framework-cms test/logs/access.log";

  root $rootpath/web;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_index Resources.php;
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.2-fpm.sock;
  }
}
```

I tried with the port 9000 as well.
i can see the index.html at the project root but not the file `web/Resources.php`.

I always have a `502 Bad Gateway`. Logs are empty.

**Edit**

I just added a line `try_files \$uri /Resources.php;` at the beginning of the `location` block. Now the php file is offered for download...

**Edit**

Thanks to @Pete Cooper, I have found that the `.sock` file is not the good one.

Here is the new version of the file :

```
server {  
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name dev.frameworkcms.com;

  set $rootpath "/var/www/html/perso/framework-cms test";  

  error_log "/var/www/html/perso/framework-cms test/logs/error.log" error;
  # combined by default
  access_log "/var/www/html/perso/framework-cms test/logs/access.log";

  root $rootpath/web;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files \$uri /Resources.php;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_index Resources.php;
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
  }
}
```

I now have a 500 Internal Server Error.
I precise that I work locally.

Comment: Does `/var/run/php7.2-fpm.sock` definitely exist in the filesystem?

Comment: What happens with a more verbose location block?: `location ~ ^.+\.php(?:/.*)?$`

Comment: The verbose code that you give does not solve my problem but now i have the good `.sock` file.

Comment: Ok, apparently my code now works but I do not know what was wrong because at some point I was not modifying the good project -_- ...

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting your php-fpm service.